# How to re-render a variable using useEffect on a new route change in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, router, use-effect

I am trying to set the width of a component when the pathname is '/'.

I have used useEffect to set the width to 800px and 1200px when on the home page and rest of the pages respectively.

However, when I use useEffect and click a button to change the route, useEffect doesn't seem to rerender the width variable.

Currently, on the initial page load, the width style does change depending on which route I am on, but when I switch routes, the change of width sizes does not occur.

In short, how can I change the width variable based on which route is currently showing?

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function Window() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null)
  let smWidth = '800px'
  let lgWidth = '1200px'

  useEffect(() => {
    let pathname = window.location.pathname
    if (pathname === '/') {
      console.log(pathname)
      setWidth(smWidth)
    } else {
      console.log(pathname)
      setWidth(lgWidth)
    }
  }, [smWidth, lgWidth])

  return (
    <WindowWrapper style={{ width }}>
     </Switch>
       <Route path="/goals" component={goals} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect has issues, you will have to listen to history changes for hooks to work, right now you are listening to [smWidth, lgWidth], which tells react, whenever these two variables changes, update the component.

Here is the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-with-width-change-yqzum?file=/src/components/App.js) link.

This should work for you.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Contactus from './Contactus';

export default withRouter(function App({ location }) {
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState(location.pathname);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();
  let smWidth = '100px';
  let lgWidth = '200px';

  useEffect(() => {
    const { pathname } = location;
    setCurrentPath(pathname);

    if (pathname === '/') {
      console.log(pathname);
      setWidth(smWidth);
    } else {
      console.log(pathname);
      setWidth(lgWidth);
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="p-1">
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary">
          Home
        </Link>
        {' - '}
        <Link to="/contactus" className="btn btn-primary">
          Contact us
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="p-1">
        <div style={{ width }} className="alert alert-info mt-1" role="alert">
          Demo Width Change: {width}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/contactus" component={Contactus} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Got it, I had an idea that smWidth and lgWidth were not going to rerender.

Comment: useEffect tells the react component on which base the component should re-render. In your code, the variables, [smWidth, lgWidth] are not changed at all. So the component isn't rerendered again.